# Restoring virtual member in SqlQuery<>()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

In order to enhance the request time of a page with a lot of data, I am trying to use Context.Database.SqlQuery method, instead of using LINQ

```
Context.Database.SqlQuery<Inschrijving>("select * from dbo.inschrijving join dbo.duif on dbo.duif.duifid = dbo.inschrijving.duifid  where vluchtid = {0} and duivenmelker_duivenmelkerid = {1}",vluchtId, duivenmelker.DuivenmelkerId);
```

This works, but in my class i use virtual members. These are null with the sqlquery method.

I have tried other types of joins, at the moment I am using a method to restore the virtual object with the id.

snippet of the class with virtual object:

```
[Key,ForeignKey("Duif"), Column(Order = 0)]
public int DuifId { get; set; }
public virtual Duif Duif { get; set; }
```

How could I restore the virtual members in the object (in a better way)?

Is there a way to do this all at once in the sqlquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I restore the virtual members in the object (in a better way)?

You would not. `SqlQuery` is able to load only top level class but not relations. You need to execute separate `SqlQuery` for every type you want to load and you should use this version instead:

```
Context.Set<Inschrijving>().SqlQuery(....);
```

That will make your entities tracked. EF will fix relationships when loaded by separate query or offer lazy loading for not loaded relations.